# OneupUploaderBundle: Files are not uploaded and UploadListener not persist to DB, why?

Tags: php, symfony, oneupuploaderbundle

I'm trying to upload one or more files using [OneupUploaderBundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pOFg.png) but I can not get it to work since files aren't uploaded and nothing is persisted to DB. I'll explain what I've done til now:

`config.yml`:

```
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
        recaudos:
            frontend: blueimp
            storage:
                service:              ~
                type:                 filesystem
                filesystem:           ~
                directory:            %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/recaudos
                stream_wrapper:       ~
                sync_buffer_size:     100K
            allowed_mimetypes:     [application/msword,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg,image/png,application/pdf,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text]
            #disallowed_mimetypes:  []
            error_handler:        oneup_uploader.error_handler.noop

            # Set max_size to -1 for gracefully downgrade this number to the systems max upload size.
            #max_size:             9223372036854775807
            use_orphanage:        true
            enable_progress:      true
            enable_cancelation:   true
            namer:                oneup_uploader.namer.uniqid
```

At Twig template only this:

```
<input id="fileUpload3" class="fileUpload" type="file" name="fileUpload3[]" data-url="{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('recaudos') }}" multiple />

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('fileUpload3').fileupload();
});
```

And latest this is the Listener for `onUpload` event:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Entity;

class UploadListener
{
    protected $doctrine;

    public function __construct($doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event, Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $tempfile = $event->getFile();

        $productoSolicitud = $em->getRepository('SolicitudProducto')->find($session->get('productoSolicitudId'));

        $recaudosTramiteProductoSolicitud = new Entity\RecaudosTramitesProductoSolicitud();
        $recaudosTramiteProductoSolicitud->setProductoSolicitud($productoSolicitud);

        $filenamePart = explode("--", $tempfile->getName());
        $pathinfo = pathinfo($tempfile->getName());
        $recaudosTramiteProductoSolicitud->setArchivo($pathinfo['filename']);

        $em->persist($recaudosTramiteProductoSolicitud);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

And of course I have service defined also:

```
appbundle.upload_listener:
    class: "AppBundle\EventListener\UploadListener"
    arguments:  [@doctrine]
    tags:
        - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: "oneup_uploader.post_persist", method: "onUpload" }
```

Did I miss something? Why file are not uploaded and data is not persisted? As you may see in the attached image there is a post request to `_uploader/recaudos/upload`, any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked my own OneupUploader implementation:

Rename your function "onUpload" to "onPostUpload" and change your service configuration to this:

```
appbundle.upload_listener:
class: "AppBundle\EventListener\UploadListener"
arguments:  [@doctrine]
tags:
    - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: oneup_uploader.post_upload, method: onPostUpload }
```

Should work, works for me.

If you need your original file name you also need an onUpload Method and this:

```
tags:
    # - {...
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.pre_upload, method: onUpload }
```

Regarding your comment:

//UploadListener

```
class UploadListener
{
    protected $originalName;

    public function onUpload(PreUploadEvent $event)
    {
        $file = $event->getFile();
        $this->originalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    }

    public function onPostUpload(PostUploadEvent $event)
    {
        $fileEntity = new YourFileEntity();
        $fileEntity->setYourOriginalNameProperty($this->originalName);
        //...
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the example for the original name? I don't know how to do that part

Comment: I'm get this error: `"Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\EventListener\UploadListener::onPostUpload() must be an instance of Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent, instance of Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostUploadEvent given in /var/www/html/project.dev/src/AppBundle/EventListener/UploadListener.php line 26"` why?

Comment: Added example for original file name.
Change ```onPostUpload(PostPersistEvent $event, $request)``` to ```onPostUpload(PostUploadEvent $event)```

Comment: As you may see on the image I'm sending an extra parameter on the form which is a hidden field, I need to access that field on the `onPostUpload` since it's part of the new entity I'm persisting, how I do that? Also I need to get some values from session, how?

Comment: Do it in **onUpload** like you originally did and store it in a private variable and access it from **onPostUpload**

Comment: Hmm I get lost, could you edit your solution adding this info? Also I'm getting this error now `"Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\EventListener\UploadListener::onUpload() must be an instance of AppBundle\EventListener\PreUploadEvent, instance of Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PreUploadEvent given in /var/www/html/project.dev/src/AppBundle/EventListener/UploadListener.php line 27"`, on `onUpload()` method

Comment: You need to add the use statment for the PreUploadEvent at the top of your class.

Comment: You can access the request like this ```$event->getRequest()```

Comment: So should be something like `$event->getRequest()->fieldName`? or what?

Comment: ```$something = $event->getRequest()->get('something', 'defaultValue');```

Comment: Fine, and last for access to `$request->getSession();` how I do that? I need to retrieve `$session->get('productoSolicitudId')` from session, how?

Comment: ```$request = $event->getRequest();```
Or ```$id = $event->getRequest()->getSession()->get('productoSolicitudId');```

Comment: `$request = $event->getRequest();` and then normally `$request->getSession()`? That?

Comment: Yes exactly. And so on.

Comment: Ok, now the persistence is working but files are not uploaded? Why is that?